# How to focus a DOM child element from a Meteor event handler

Tags: dom, meteor

I have an event handler that sets a session variable to change the content within a DOM element -- in this case a table cell.

```
'dblclick td.itemName': function (evt) {
  Session.set("editItemName",true);
  evt.currentTarget.children[0].focus();
},


                <td class="itemName">
                {{#unless editItemName}}
                    {{name}} 
                {{else}}
                    <input class="editItemName" type="text" value="{{name}}" style="width:100px;">
                {{/unless}}
                </td>
```

Pretty straight forward...

However evt.currentTarget.children doesnt work. Once the input takes place of the text, I'd like to make it automatically focus... The meteor docs say that this is a DOM object so its weird that the children function doesnt work...

Thanks

Chet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you double click, and your function runs, you set the session `editItemName` to true, and then you're trying to give the input-element focus, but the template has not been re-rendered yet, so the input-element hasn't been created (the template will be re-rendered some time after your function returns). In other words: `evt.currentTarget.children[0]` is not a reference to the input-element.

**Possible solution 1**

In HTML 5 there's an attribute called autofocus, which you can use (at least I can in Chrome). Just add it to the input-element:

```html
<input autofocus="autofocus" class="editItemName" type="text" value="{{name}}" style="width:100px;">
```

**Possible solution 2**

Otherwise you have to focus it with JavaScript when the template been rendered and your input-element exists in it:

```js
Template.yourTemplate.rendered = function(){

    var input = this.find('.editItemName')

    if(input){
        input.focus()
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah. Interesting... That makes sense though. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @Chet See my improved answer.

Comment: I think I am going to use x-editable... Apparently I can use that with meteorite. Not sure. Still learning...

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to set the focus to a DOM element that has not been rendered yet.

The issue has been bothering me for a while. I have tried to use the `autofocus='autofocus'` HTML attribute: it has no effect in Firefox, and in Chrome, it seems to only work the first time the element is rendered.

So we need a handler that is called just after the template is rendered, in order to set the focus with javascript. `Template.templateName.rendered` looks like the way to go, but there is an issue:

**What didn't work for me:**

```
<template name="itemName">
    <td class="itemName">
    {{#unless editItemName}}
        {{name}} 
    {{else}}
        <input type="text" value="{{name}}">
    {{/unless}}
    </td>
</template>

Template.itemName.rendered = function()
{
    this.$('input').focus() 
}
```

When doing this, `Template.yourTemplate.rendered` seems to fire only the first time you click on the item (you get the focus correctly only once).

**What worked for me:**

```
<template name="itemName">
    <td class="itemName">
    {{#unless editItemName}}
        {{name}} 
    {{else}}
        {{> itemNameEdit}}
    {{/unless}}
    </td>
</template>

<template name="itemNameEdit">
    <input type="text" value="{{name}}">
</template>

Template.itemNameEdit.rendered = function()
{
    this.$('input').focus() 
}
```

Any explanation from a Meteor expert?

Comment: In a more recent meteor release, they changed some of the functionality of template.rendered(). Rendered used to get called whenever information in that template was re-rendered. Now that they are using the Blade template system, only the parts of the template that need to be re-rendered will be re-rendered and Template.rendered will only get called once: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#rendered-callback-only-fires-once

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now understand why splitting into 2 templates works: the second template `itemNameEdit` is added and removed from the DOM each time the user edits the item name, triggering `Template.itemNameEdit.rendered` when needed. It is not the case with `Template.itemName.rendered`, which is called only once because `itemNameEdit` stays in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

As @Chet [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116369/how-to-focus-a-dom-child-element-from-a-meteor-event-handler#comment35628815_23262955), Template.[name].rendered no longer fires whenever a template is updated, but instead, only when the template is *first* rendered, and [only once](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#rendered-callback-only-fires-once).

One can pass a callback to [Tracker.afterFlush](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_afterflush) which will fire every time the template is updated.
i.e. [all reactive updates are processed](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_flush)

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'dblclick td.itemName': function(e, t) {
    Session.set("editItemName",true);

    Tracker.afterFlush(function() {
      this.find('input').focus();
    }.bind(t));
  }
});
```