# How to focus on a newly created input element in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Consider this requirement.

In template, there is

- a button to insert a blank record into Meteor Collection
- a list of input element represented the collection which can edit value of the record

When I pressed the button, the input element with blank record will be displayed into html because of Meteor's reactivity. 
But how to set the input to be auto-focused when created?

I know maybe setting an ID into `session` and judging it in `rendered` function will be a solution. Is there any easier way to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

In standard HTML5, autofocus=autofocus as an attribute for one input does this, and there are jquery  or javascript shims to bring this backward.  Using the session to store an id can be used to make the template data redisplay when you change the session, but the focus concept is still a distinct problem.

Answer (score 0):

I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116369/how-to-focus-a-dom-child-element-from-a-meteor-event-handler/23262955#23262955) about using `Template.templateName.rendered` for that purpose.